# Use awk to set the title of a data series in gnuplot, based on the filename

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I'm trying to use gnuplot to compare several data files. I get those files through a list, using an `ls` command, and then I plot those files.

```
List = "`echo $(ls GRID/3D/Ratio_5/DATA.dat.* | sort -V )`"
```

This gives me a list of files `DATA.dat.0001 DATA.dat.0002 ... DATA.dat.0100` representing different times, and then I can plot them using

```
plot for [i in List] i u 1:2 title system('basename '.i)
```

In that case, no issues. However, in some cases, I need to compare different `Ratio_` directories (no time dependence here), so I create my list

```
List = "`echo $(ls GRID/3D/Ratio_*/DATA.dat | sort -V )`"
```

But the same plot command gives all my series the same name: `DATA.dat`. I tried

```
plot for [i in List] i u 1:2 title system('dirname '.i)
```

but it prints the whole path except `DATA.dat`, and I'm just interested on the `Ratio_` number.

I create a function to extract the Ratio from the filename string

```
Ratio(filename) = "awk -F / '{print $3}' ".filename
plot for [i in List] i u 1:2 title Ratio(i)
```

but it just print the whole thing `awk -F / '{print $3}' GRID/3D/Ratio_1/DATA.dat` for every data series. I tried to add a `system` call within the definition of `Ratio(filename)` without success

```
Ratio(filename)=system("awk '{print $3}' " .filename)
plot for [i in List] i u 1:2 title Ratio(i)
```

but now each data series is named like the whole 3rd column of the corresponding DATA.dat, with its several hundred lines.

I'm out of ideas. This is probably just a simple syntax problem, a misplaced quote, point or comma. I know I can call my gnuplot script in the `3D` directory and use `dirname` option, but that's not what I want. I'm calling this script along with many others placed in the same directory, to create plots for a scientific article, and placing those scripts in different places would be a mess.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
Ratio(filename) = "awk -F / '{print $3}' ".filename
```

you are just creating a string, not executing it. Furthermore, when you do

```
Ratio(filename)=system("awk '{print $3}' " .filename)
```

you're asking awk to parse the file's content, rather than its name. Try:

```
Ratio(filename)=system("echo ".filename." | awk -F / '{print $3}'")
```

Comment: I can't check this right now, let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. Nice trick and explanation of my issue. It works. Thanks again

Comment: I actually used this, to improve the look of the labels a bit more

`Ratio(filename)=system("echo ".filename." | awk -F / '{print $3}' | sed 's/\_/=/'")`

But I'm sure there are other possibly better options, like adding a `END{}` clause to the `awk` command. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote `List` to preserve the linefeeds in it when you pass it to `awk`. Compare the following:

```
List=$(ls GRID/3D/Ratio*/DATA.dat)
echo "$List"
GRID/3D/Ratio_1/DATA.dat
GRID/3D/Ratio_2/DATA.dat

echo $List
GRID/3D/Ratio_1/DATA.dat GRID/3D/Ratio_2/DATA.dat
```

and this:

```
awk -F\/ '{print $3}' <<< $list


awk -F\/ '{print $3}' <<< "$List"
Ratio_1
Ratio_2
```

Comment: Sorry @Mark, I just saw the answer. Thanks. Your comment is correct, but it doesn't apply in my issue, as I'm doing this within a gnuplot script. The `List` isn't modified by the `shell`. I need the full path in order to open the result files that I want to plot. And I don't think I can create another list with the modifications you mention to get only the `Ratio` part of the path, as I don't know how to match the entries of that `Ratio` list with the plotted files.